# RecyclerView not displaying correct shape when using scroll

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

in the course of my CHAT project I came across the following situation, in the first view of the RecyclerView the texts appear correctly, but as soon as I use the scroll , the view is all messed up, some spaces are blank, I don't know where I can be making mistakes

[image]

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.skydevices.watsappclone.R;
import com.skydevices.watsappclone.helper.UsuarioFirebase;
import com.skydevices.watsappclone.model.Mensagem;


import java.util.List;

public class MensagensAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MensagensAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Mensagem> mensagens;
    private Context context;
    private static final int TIPO_REMETENTE     = 0;
    private static final int TIPO_DESTINATARIO  = 1;

    public MensagensAdapter(List<Mensagem> lista, Context c) {
        this.mensagens = lista;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View item = null;
        if ( viewType == TIPO_REMETENTE ){
            item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_mensagem_remetente, parent, false);
        }else if( viewType == TIPO_DESTINATARIO ){
            item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_mensagem_destinatario, parent, false);
        }

        return new MyViewHolder(item);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Mensagem mensagem = mensagens.get( position );
        String msg = mensagem.getMensagem();
        String imagem = mensagem.getImagem();

        if ( imagem != null ){
            Uri url = Uri.parse( imagem );
            Glide.with(context).load(url).into( holder.imagem );

            //Esconder o texto
            holder.mensagem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else {
            holder.mensagem.setText( msg );
            //Esconder a imagem
            holder.imagem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mensagens.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Mensagem mensagem = mensagens.get( position );
        String idUsuario = UsuarioFirebase.getIdentificadorUsuario();

        if ( idUsuario.equals( mensagem.getIdUsuario() ) ){
            return TIPO_REMETENTE;
        }

        return TIPO_DESTINATARIO;

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mensagem;
        ImageView imagem;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mensagem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textoMensagemTexto);
            imagem   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMensagemFoto);

        }
    }

}
```

I reviewed the entire adapter and I don't know where the problem could be